# Magento CE 1.7.0.2: Move Terms and Conditions in Onepage Checkout to Step 4 Payment Information

Tags: magento-1.7

because of skipping the Review Page for Paypal Express I want to move the Tems and Conditions to the Payment Information as the customer should accept them after selecting Paypal Express (only available payment method) in the Onepage Checkout process.

I managed everything using this Answers
[Terms and condition on checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45263/terms-and-condition-on-checkout-page)
except making the checkbox mandatory.

As far I understood there needs to be a modification in the

```
..\app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php
```

The check

```
    if ($requiredAgreements = Mage::helper('checkout')->getRequiredAgreementIds()) {
        $postedAgreements = array_keys($this->getRequest()->getPost('agreement', array()));
        if ($diff = array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements)) {
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.');
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            return;
        }
    }
```

has to be moved from saveOrderAction() to **savePaymentAction()**

savePaymentAction() has another structure ... if anybody managed this some help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Kozure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following solution.

The terms and condition was moved to the 1. Step "Billing Information".

***/app/design/frontend/default//layout/checkout.xml***

add after line 323:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml">
   <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
</block>
```

add after line 339:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/checkout/review.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

comment out line 417:

```
<!-- <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>-->
```

The result is as followed, the check box is mandatory.

[image]