# How to Debug Shopping Cart Pricing Rule Error?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping, zipcode

Shopping Cart Price Rule - By using ZIP Code and Subtotal - Free shipping Not Working

**Shipping Method : Webshop Matrix Rate**

I am applied Shopping Cart Price Rule using zipcode,

[image]
[image]
[image]

May I know where I did the error?

Error Log:

```
2018-10-03T10:47:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Displayfreeprice/Model/Freeprice.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/abc/public_html/app/code/local:/home/abc/public_html/app/code/community:/home/abc/public_html/app/code/core:/home/abc/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/abc/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Comment: Have you set zip code condition?

Comment: Yes, my customer zip code 600094, still not apply free shipping. May i know how to solve this error?

Comment: please check my answer and let me know it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this condition and check.

**CONDITIONS**

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

Shipping Postcode  is  600094

**ACTIONS**

- Set “Apply” to “Percent of product price discount”
- Set “Discount Amount” to “0”
- Set “Free Shipping” to “For shipment with matching
  items”

Comment: I need to apply free shipping  range like from : 600003 to: 600151, individually enter is not good. am right?

Comment: My condition : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyKJn.png

Comment: Yes, it will works

Comment: Its not working,

Comment: First, try with single zipcode and check it. also check log there is any error?

Comment: Today morning i am received order, the subtotal is above 500, but the shipping cost is applied, may i know the possibilities of error?

Comment: Provide ACTIONS tab screenshot. so i check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77145/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-zus).

Answer (score 1):

I would double check if the free shipping method is enabled in the store. Setting up the cart rule alone is not enough if the Free Shipping method is disabled it will not work

Refer to this http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-free-shipping.html (step 1)

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment ... If this error is logged on save rule, I doubt you problem is related to conditions

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Displayfreeprice/Model/Freeprice.php' for inclusion ...

Seem there is something wrong in one of your `config.xml` or maybay in non-existing frontend/backend-model ...

Yor can try something like `grep -i 'freeprice'` to search where this model is declared or maybe `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` could give some info.