# Agreements missing in checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I am running a **Magento 1.9.3.1** store and the agreements are not shown in the checkout. I tried going back to the default theme, checked if there are any agreements and if they are enabled. Nothing helped, they are never shown, not even in the default theme.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you have defined terms in Magento under

> Sales > Terms and conditions

Ensure that you have terms enabled in

> System Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options > Enable
>   Terms and Conditions

If already enabled from above then you need to check it in codebase, follow this in case of code edit
[Terms and condition on checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45263/terms-and-condition-on-checkout-page)

Comment: Like I said, there are active and enabled ... let me check out that link now :). Thanks!